# Populating the row of an ArrayAdapter with a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a fragment `ArticleFragment` which is passed an `Article` object.
The `ArticleFragment` is usually displayed in an Activity but I would like to reuse the fragment inside a ListView. Each row of the ListView should hold an instance of `ArticleFragment`.
I know that I can customize a row with the `getView()` method of the adapter but the UI displayed by the `ArticleFragment` is very much alike as that of a row so it would be annoying to have to update it at two positions if the UI changes.

`ArticleFragment.java`

```
public class ArticleFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    static final String ARTICLE_PARCEL_KEY = "parcelable_article";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected static ArticleFragment newInstance(Article article) {
        ArticleFragment f = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle(Article.class.getClassLoader());
        args.putParcelable(ARTICLE_PARCEL_KEY, article);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    Article getArticle() {
        return getArguments().getParcelable(ARTICLE_PARCEL_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.article, container, false);
        ArticleImagesFragment imagesFragment = ArticleImagesFragment.newInstance(getArticle().getImages());
        FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.images_fragment_container, imagesFragment);
        if (getActivity() instanceof ArticleActivity) {
            DisqusCommentsFragment disqusFragment =  DisqusCommentsFragment.newInstance(getArticle().getCommentsUrl());
            ft.add(R.id.comments_fragment_container, disqusFragment);
        }
        ft.commit();
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Article article = getArticle();

        TextView kickerView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kicker);
        kickerView.setText(article.getKicker().toUpperCase());

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleView.setText(article.getTitle());

        String commentsText = "Jetzt kommentieren!";
        if (article.getNumComments() == 1) {
            commentsText = article.getNumComments().toString() + " Kommentar";
        } else if (article.getNumComments() > 1) {
            commentsText = article.getNumComments().toString() + " Kommentare";
        }
        TextView numCommentsView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num_comments);
        numCommentsView.setText(commentsText);

        TextView pubDateView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pub_date);
        String dateText = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMM, hh:mm").format(article.getPubDate());
        pubDateView.setText(dateText);

        TextView authorNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author_name);
        authorNameView.setText(article.getAuthorName());

        TextView articleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        articleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(article.getHtmlContent()));
    }
}
```

I noticed that it's possible to pass a custom row layout to the `ArrayAdapter` but that would again duplicate the logic for displaying the UI of an Article. Instead I would prefer to pass a fragment to the constructor of the adapter and use it to display the row.

Is it possible to achieve this with an `ArrayAdapter`?
If not what would be the right path to take to achieve the reuse of the `ArticleFragment` in a ListView?

Thanks for your help!